# Oracle - updating the column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, trying to update a column in the same table - like if the column has value 636180 then with 3 as below

```
update TABLE_A
set wid = (
select distinct case wid
when 636180 then 3
when 636181 then 5
else wid 
end new_wid
from TABLE_A where rownum < 100);
```

It errors out as

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
update TABLE_A 
set wid = case when wid = 636180 then 3 
               when wid = 636181 then 5 
               else wid 
          end
where rownum < 100
```

or to only update the records having the relevant `wid`s

```
update TABLE_A 
set wid = case when wid = 636180 then 3 
               when wid = 636181 then 5 
          end
where wid in (636180, 636181)
```

Comment: To avoid unnecessary updates on records that don't change, I'd omit the "else wid" and add a where condition for the two values that should change